# Intellij IDEA Maven Import problems

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I wanted to switch to IntelliJ for forge modding (minecraft). When I do what they are saying to do on internet, I get a maven error...

```
            Unindexed remote maven repositories found. Disable...
            The following repositories used in your gradle projects were not indexed yet: 
            http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven
            If you want to use dependency completion for these repositories artifacts,
            Open Repositories List, select required repositories and press "Update" button
```

When I click update, it loads for half a second and then gives the same error again... I searched on internet and nobody seems to have my problem... help please ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors. It may fail with OutOfMemory error in which case you can try increasing the [heap size for Maven Importer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/maven-importing.html) (VM options for importer) and [IDE heap size](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869).

Try not to exceed 750-1024m for `-Xmx` value if you are running on a 32-bit JVM (default), otherwise it may [crash or fail to start](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241105).

If you need to use more heap, [switch to 64-bit Java](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879) and specify the same 64-bit JVM for Maven (JDK for importer) in IntelliJ IDEA settings.

Another possible case is if IDE cannot connect to the Maven process. On some systems it's needed to edit the `hosts` file so that `localhost` [resolves correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702961/104891).

There was also a [bug caused by Nvidia driver](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000078444-Can-t-open-maven-projects-and-Unable-to-import-maven-project-error) (java process was crashing). Make sure you have the latest driver if this applies to your hardware.

If all the above doesn't help, share your `idea.log` file.

Note that indexing repositories is not required for working with a project, but it may indicate that Maven fails to work for one of the reasons above (or some other). See if the dependencies for the project were imported and if you can build the imported project in IDEA.

Some repositories [cannot be indexed at all](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-138029), in this case just ignore the error.

Comment: Just curious, what was exactly the problem in your case?

Comment: Well i think it was Intellij because there was an error but it would run perfect even with it.... but i corrected it and it does the same.... guess visual bug or something....

Comment: Removing .idea folder & increasing the heap helped me.... Thanks @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have different JDK versions on the project, e.g. project expects to work under JDK 8, as all the credentials were setup using that version, and after importing project from the git, newer IntelliJ Idea bundled with JDK 17, will setup project to use this newer version.

---

In that case, maven won't be able to import all the necessary dependencies. 
So, check :

- IntelliJ's "Open Module Settings" and check "Project", and "Modules" to inspect a JDK version
- IndelliJ's settings : "Build/executions/deployment" -> Build tools/Maven
- Check Importing and Runner to use exact the same JDK version

Hope this will help