# IntelliJ IDEA does not recognise maven dependencies (omitted for conflict with ...)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I loaded a Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA, when I run 'mvn clean package' in the terminal, it works fine, but IntelliJ IDEA can not debug or build it and in the UI, maven project tab, shows the following (red line on dependencies):

omitted for conflict with STH

[image]
How should I fix it?

Comment: try right-clicking the pom.xml -> Maven -> Reimport. Did it help?

Comment: What Maven version do you use for importing? See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891) helps to resolve the problem.

Comment: Do you have any unchecked profiles?

Comment: I use Maven (3.3.9) 
I tried pom.xml -> Maven -> Reimport, but it does not help!

Comment: Which "User settings file:" is being used in IntelliJ - same one as per command line (`M2_HOME`) ??

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem with an enterprise application. I will fix it soon and share my solution here.

Comment: After reimporting I just restarted my client and found that this has been resolved. I made sure that it is not happening due to some conflicts by conflicting dependencies by generating dependency tree using "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbos" before though.

Comment: Can you show your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Perhaps it's to do with `Dependency Management`?

Comment: After restarting IntelliJ the issue was gone. I'm using IntelliJ 2017.2.5.

Answer (score 7):

Re imported and restart(Invalidate Caches / Restart) the IntelliJ. that was working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

Instead of

```
File > Open
```

used

```
File > New > Import from Existing Sources
```

and it worked

Comment: Unfortunately, that trick did not work with me.  IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (Ultimate Edition).

Answer (score 0):

You can do File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart... The errors will be gone after IntelliJ restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Just rebooting IntelliJ did the trick for me. Simple but effective.

Comment: could you explain why doing that It was resolved? otherwise, I think that this is more a comment than a solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an old project of mine which was developed with Eclipse. I had to go to switch to an older version of maven and not the build-in version from intelliJ. *settings > maven > change maven home directory*

Answer (score 0):

Check if the jar is downloaded in m2 folder , if it is downloaded and its not showing in intellij then add the same maven dependency in module where you are trying to use the classes in the jar.