# Warning with maven repository in build.gradle in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am trying to setup a new scala project in IntelliJ (2016.3.4,  built on January 31, 2017) with gradle. My build.gradle is as given below:

```
group 'org.microservices.architecture'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.1'
}

tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.daemonServer = true
    ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.fork = true
    ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.useAnt = false
    ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.useCompileDaemon = false
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: 'akka-actor_2.11', version: '2.4.17'
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.12.1'
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:3.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['src/scala']
        }
    }
    test {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['test/scala']
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I get following warning message:

> The following repositories used in your gradle projects were not indexed yet: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2.
>
> If you want to use dependency completion for these repositories
> artifacts, Open Repositories List, select required repositories and
> press "Update" button.

Comment: The warning seems to be self-explanatory. What is the problem? BTW small hint: for your source sets you can use a 1 liner as well like `sourceSets.main.scala.srcDir 'src/scala' `

Comment: I think that is not a problem, because IntelliJ can download dependencies, but IDE show that message as warning. 

And, thanks for your small hint ;)

Comment: Even if IntelliJ got a nice boost to support Gradle in 2017.3.* it's still not ideal with integration, mine still moan about dependencies cannot be applied to a closure ;)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891) if there is a problem with repository indexing.