# Maven dependency for GSON 2.8.0 in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have dependency in my pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

but IDEA is telling me that can't see version 2.8.0, only version 2.2.4.
But I can see new version at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0

Maybe I just don't know how to set up repository?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891) for the general diagnostics of common issues in Maven integrations.

Comment: To CrazyCoder, thank you, I did everything but nothing helped me.

Comment: The first step is to always verify that a command line build of your project works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just used it like this:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

And it worked fine for me.