# Whats the matter of the folder hierarchy my project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Today when I open my project, there is some problem in my folder hierarchy, you can see the below, there is no packages here:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

In general, the common folder hierarchy should like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**EDIT**

I have tried reopen the project and reopen my IntelliJ IDEA.
Both do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `.idea` directory and `*.iml` files, then **Open** `pom.xml` from the Welcome screen.

This issue can happen if `.idea/modules.xml` is corrupted or if any of the `*.iml` files are not found/invalid.

Reimporting the project from Maven should help. In case it doesn't work, [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891) for diagnostics.