# There is red wavy line under the dependencies - maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I don't know what this means:

[image]

The dependency is added by me in my `pom.xml`.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xwork/xwork -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xwork</groupId>
        <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But you can see in the picture, there is red wave line under the `xwork` library.

I have tried use:

1. Maven Lifecycle : `clean - install`
2. Refresh Maven and Download Sources
3. Reopen IntelliJ IDEA

But this did not work for me. Does anyone know what causes this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This dependency is provided by a third-party repository, you need to add the following to your `pom.xml`:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>xwork</id>
      <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Then Reimport the project in IntelliJ IDEA (you may also need to close and open the project again), then verify that the dependency is present in the **Project** view under **External Libraries** node:

[image: xwork]

There is also no more error in the **Maven Projects** tool window:

[image: maven]

If it still doesn't work for you, [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891) for the diagnostics.

Comment: wa~o, I get it. why you know so much?

Comment: It's my job to know a lot and help others.