# Packages exist in .m2 folder but built error - Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

i start a project in my computer while a go and i had git it into a repo, after a while i was going to use that code. i clone my files from gitlab and there was no problem.my project used Maven. but after cloning when i tried to run project i got error.
`Error:(22, 23) java: package org.json.simple does not exist`

and a lot of same errors that says that libraries not added even i have them all in my external libraries.

here my External Libraries:
[external libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr3lD.png)

and here is my maven pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>LawnMower-Odroid</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/eu.hansolo/Medusa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
            <artifactId>Medusa</artifactId>
            <version>7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/eu.hansolo/tilesfx -->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.4.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.2.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kordamp.ikonli/ikonli-weathericons-pack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-weathericons-pack</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kordamp.ikonli/ikonli-material-pack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-material-pack</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kordamp.ikonli/ikonli-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kordamp.ikonli/ikonli-materialdesign-pack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-materialdesign-pack</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kordamp.ikonli/ikonli-javafx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lynden/GMapsFX -->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.lynden</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>GMapsFX</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.10.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.datafx/flow -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.datafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>flow</artifactId>
            <version>8.0b8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.datafx/core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.datafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>8.0b8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.rxtx/rxtx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.rxtx</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxtx</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.json</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>json</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>20160810</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**EDITED:**

i should explain that there are no errors in my IDE's code editor.Just and Just when i build my project errors will show up as picture bellow:

[no error in IDE's Code Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3dfG.png)

and if i add libraries jar file to project manually the errors will gone!!!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891). Try to remove .idea directory and reimport the project from `pom.xml`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder i tried that and it wasn't helpful... i should explain that there are no error in my IDE code editor...JUST AND JUST when building Errors will show up. i will update question up there for you.

Comment: Check [build.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085). Do you have `MAVEN_REPOSITORY` [path variable](http://i.imgur.com/CVE4slv.png) specified correctly?

Comment: @CrazyCoder i use maven repository and path variables are specified correctly and .jar files are downloaded but still build errors exist. i tried to clone project on another device. there were no problem on other devices!!! but other devices are slow so i cant work with them. so i will be glad if any suggest helps me

Comment: You need to investigate build.log file and see if there is anything wrong with the paths inside it.

Comment: i did that but no avail at end.thanks tho.