# Spring Hello World Web App on Intellij

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, jboss

This is my first Spring Application ever. I am trying to display Hello,World in my browser. I followed the steps below, but something is wrong with my dependencies. I am using Intellij 1.2017

- Installed zip from https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/#initial
- copied `initial` directory to my file system

On Intellij:

- Import project
- choose ../initial/pom.xml
- Next -> selected `org.springframework:gs-maven:0.1.0` -> jdk 1.8 -> Finish
- run: everything works fine up to here.

Now I want to dispaly Hello, World! in the browser, follwoing the steps here: `http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/`

- Added class `SampleController`
- Modified pom.xml to be as follows:

> ```
> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>     <artifactId>gs-maven</artifactId>
>     <packaging>jar</packaging>
>     <version>0.1.0</version>
>     <parent>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>         <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
>     </parent>
>     <dependencies>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>         </dependency>
>     </dependencies>
>     <build>
>         <plugins>
>             <plugin>
>                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
>                 <version>2.1</version>
>                 <executions>
>                     <execution>
>                         <phase>package</phase>
>                         <goals>
>                             <goal>shade</goal>
>                         </goals>
>                         <configuration>
>                             <transformers>
>                                 <transformer
>                                     implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
>                                     <mainClass>hello.HelloWorld</mainClass>
>                                 </transformer>
>                             </transformers>
>                         </configuration>
>                     </execution>
>                 </executions>
>             </plugin>
>         </plugins>
>     </build>
> ```

- right click on project, and add framework support -> Added spring
- Getting: cannot resolve symbole boot, and : cannot resolve symbole EnableAutoConfiguration

[image]

I do not have much experience on maven, and dependencies, hence I am trying to follow the instructions literally. What could be wrong in my steps?

Comment: I dont think the dependencies are loaded/retrieved, så try running 'mvn clean install' or use intellij maven plugin to refresh the depenedencies.

Comment: @MohsanShakir How do I use intellij maven plugin to refresh the dependencies?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining comment from – Mohsan Shakir

1. Click on "View" and enable "Tool Buttons".
2. On the right panel click on "Maven Projects"
3. Add (by click on +) you project (find the pom file).
4. Click the leftmost button on the maven panel "Reimport All..."

Comment: Thank you. I did that. But it did not help. names are still resolved!

Comment: Did you install Maven properly? Do you have M2_HOME etc? If yes try to specify the Idea Maven setting on the same panel and point to your maven dir