# Why my maven get so many red wave lines below their dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I open the project by IntelliJ IDEA, the project is created by eclipse, and I have refreshed my maven, and downloaded the sources.

Why I still get so much red wave line under my every dependencies?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Some one know how to solve that?

Comment: What does it say when you hover over it?

Comment: "red lines" usually have error messages that belong to them. Without those messages it is almost impossible to tell what the exact problem is.

Comment: It looks like you need to reimport your project. If you've done that and you still have the red lines try maven in a shell -- cd to your project root and type `mvn clean install`. Then take a look in the `~/.m2/repository` folder to see if it's full of interesting things, like junit. Once you've run mvn from a shell, try reimporting into idea. Finally, close your project and choose 'open', then select your project's root pom, then tell intellij to create a new project and not reuse anything from the old one.

Comment: @EngineerDollery How to do with that?

Comment: So by "refreshing my Maven" you mean? Usually you also have to re build your project in order to dependencies to be found

Comment: @GrayCygnus Can not find most lib of maven, some can find .

Comment: @EngineerDollery when I cd in the root of my project, then use `mvn clean all`, I get the error:`-bash: mvn: command not found`

Comment: Are you sure you added all the dependencies you need (and the correct version) in your file?

Comment: @DaveNewton Shows nothing.

Comment: @s-n-2 -- install docker-machine, then in the docker bash shell, change to your project root and run `docker run -it --rm -v /`pwd`:/work -w /work maven bash`. Then run mvn clean install.

Comment: @EngineerDollery That seems a pretty extreme solution for a Maven dependency issue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891

Comment: @DaveNewton -- I wouldn't call docker extreme. It's rather simple to use for development in this way, as long as you're told how to use it. It's not like I'm asking the OP to build a fully automated dynamically scaled software development pipeline with fully containerised copies of the production environment. I just want to see what happens with a standardised environment and this pom.

Comment: It'll work fine--it's not a Maven issue, it's an IDE issue. If he ran it from the command line it'd be fine.

Comment: @DaveNewton -- how do you know? (personally I think the OP doesn't know how to use maven and has made everything a system dependency but the libs aren't where the pom points to -- answer, remove all system dependencies).

Comment: @EngineerDollery Because it's an IDE/project configuration issue, delta the potential issue at the top of their pom. Which would be made obvious by running it from the command line, no VM or clean-room required.

Comment: but they don't have it installed...

Answer (score 0):

Intellij may have a problem getting dependencies from your Maven repository due to a certificate. If you are using Artifactory, and the URL starts with HTTPS, you may need to add the certificate to Intellij's truststore.

Here are the steps:

In a terminal:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername <hostname> -connect <hostname>:443 </dev/null
```

Copy the lines from -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- to -----END CERTIFICATE----- into a file called artifactory.cert.

Then, in the terminal:

```
keytool -import -file artifactory.cert -alias artifactory -keystore C:\truststores\intellij.truststore.jks
```

When it prompts for the password, enter a password.

In Intellij, choose Help > Edit Custom VM Options (it may prompt you to create the file the first time).

Add the following JVM arguments:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\truststores\intellij.truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<the password you created above>
```

If things still do not work, try closing the project, deleting the project's .idea directory, and opening the project.

Answer (score -1):

First I can not recommend to use `<scope>system</scope>` dependencies. Always try to prevent them cause it shows that you didn't understand the concept of Maven by using dependencies which are automatically handled which means downloaded either from Maven Central or from a corporate repository manager.

If you do you use them than use them correct which means like this:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>..</groupId>
       <artifactId>..</artifactId>
       <version>..</version>
       <scope>system</scope>
       <systemPath>...</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```

The problem is that you have same parts of that somewhere else in the pom.xml file where it not belongs...

Comment: despite your excellent rep, I don't think you read the question properly. I really don't think that his problem is a single errant system dependency.

Comment: You can of course think that way but a pom file has a defined XSD and if this is not fulfilled the IDE can't read that correctly which means it can't be interpreted correctly which results in errors. So I would suggest to first fix the problems and afterwards we see further. Apart from that I would always suggest to check the build on command line first and if this is Ok than go a step further to an IDE...

Comment: I can see systemPath in the code -- I think the hover-over could be obscuring the one you're referring to.