# My maven get stuck in Resolving Maven dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

My maven get stuck in Resolving Maven dependencies.

[image]

How to solve this issue? some one know ?

Comment: Are you using a proxy ?

Comment: @Mickaël B No, I am not.

Comment: Did you try with maven command line in debug mode to see what happens ?

Comment: @MickaëlB How to do with that?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Comment: You must be behind a corporate proxy. Ask your sysadmin to give proxy settings and add them to your settings.xml in maven and also in Network configuration in IDE.