# Maven dependencies can only be resolved one by one in intellij

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea

I have quite a large project using maven POM's for dependencies. My IDE is intellij idea 2017.1, maven has version 3.3.9. Everything was fine until a few days ago when I switched git branch inside intellij. Suddenly nothing can be found anymore, the only way to resolve a maven project is to actively tell intellij to reload that specific project using Maven > Reimport like this: [image: maven import]

This has to be done for every project, in correct order and takes forever. I have tried to reimport all, clear intellij cahce and restart, remove .idea folder, remove project and sync again from git, clear everything in .m2 repo, clear all target folders, and even bumped intellij from 2016.3 to 2017.1. Nothing has been successful yet, and I am quite puzzled as to why this happens.

Comment: Can you build the project on the command line?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Comment: @JFMeier Yes, it seems to be an intellij issue only

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you!! I did never think that it could be a memory issue, but found a lot of `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` now. Bumping Xmx did the trick. Probably why it could reload one module, but not all.