# mvn clean install works but intellij does not compile project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I saw many people who faced that kind of problem before. I tried what they tried to solve the issue but still unfortunately no success.

I can run mvn clean install succesfully and nothing sees problem but unfortunately at Intellij(latest version), I can not compile the project. It says unable to compile the project. I invalidated caces, tried maven reimporting, deleted .iml and pom, checked settings javac compiler but everything seems find and still it does not compile. It is going to make me mad soon. Please help.

Comment: Are you really using Maven 2?

Comment: I am very sorry. I am using maven 3.1

Comment: Please show your pom.xml file

Comment: Can you post what errors you are seeing in IntelliJ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ settings you can check that you are using Javac (build,execution,deployment > compiler > java compiler) as a Java compiler and not AJC, Eclipse... or another compiler.