# Can't import any downloaded maven dependency, if IntelliJ IDEA behind proxy

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, proxy

I was configure my settings.xml for corp proxy server like this

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>securecentral</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>securecentral</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>

  </profiles>

  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>***.***.***.***</host>
      <port>****</port>
      <username>******</username>
      <password>******</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

and got the possibility of downloading dependencies. But if with downloading its ok, when i try to import something to class, idea cant find any downloaded dependency and mark as red all after top domain level. Can to see only base libraries (which was included by default) when i put the dot after org. for example.

In .m2 folder all necessary libraries is downloaded

In settings -> build tools -> maven all as default

Any new dependencies downloads successfully

pom.xml without any errors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId1</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Somebody have any idea about that? 
Any advise will be helpful!

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Try to delete `.idea` directory and reimport the project from `pom.xml`. Also make sure the [proxy is configured in the IDE too](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/http-proxy.html).

Comment: @CrazyCoder was try that, but IDEA still cant see my dependencies, and all plugins and dependencies are underlined red, in Maven Project Bar

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use?

Comment: @CrazyCoder IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5 Build #IC-171.4694.70

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. idea.log may have more details.