# can not resolve symbol erros in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng, junit4

I am learning selenium testing using java with Intellij as the IDE and maven as the package manager.

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>depositTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>deposittest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My import statements are as follows:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertEquals;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```

However, I get `can not resolve symbol errors` for the testng and junit libraries in the IDE. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try Import option in Maven sidebar?

Comment: Set it to autoimport and reimported umpteen number of times.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. Make sure it works from the command line, outside of IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified `<scope>test</scope>` in your `<dependency>` section for both `JUnit` and `TestNG`.

So those libraries are meant to be used only within `src/test/java`.

Please check if you are referring to these classes in `src/main/java`.

IntelliJ will not resolve the JUnit and TestNG classes in `src/main/java`

To fix your problem, please remove the `<scope>` tag from your `<dependency>` for both TestNG and JUnit, and try again.

Comment: I also faced the issue and this worked