# Apache Ignite - Why InteliJ is not recognizing Kafka dependency?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ignite

Currently I have POM MVN file in InteliJ and for the most part - it recognizes all Apache Ignite dependencies but not Kafka one.

This is Dependency part in POM:

```
 <!-- Apache Ignite dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-log4j</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried changing version to 2.0.0, 1.9.0, 1.8.0 etc. but still showing error bellow:

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Answer (score 0):

`ignite-kafka` artifact is definitely in Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.ignite%7Cignite-kafka%7C2.1.0%7Cjar

Make sure that you reimport Maven projects in IDEA.

I would also try to build using Maven from command line and check if there are any errors.