# IntelliJ maven dependency not getting resolved for all

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to import a maven project into IntelliJ. My PC is connected via a proxy to the internet. I have put in the required proxy details as

> -Xmx768m -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=10.78.20.500 -DproxyPort=8100

in the **VM options for Importer** under **Maven -> Importing**
 I checked the .m2 folder, where many of the files are in the **.lastUpdated** format.
Below are a few screenshots from IntelliJ.

[image: **Libraries**]

[image: **Problems**]

I've also tried the steps mentioned here.
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206903515-Not-all-Maven-dependencies-appear-in-External-libraries- but it hasn't helped.

Please tell me how this can be solved.

Comment: try right-clicking on the pom.xml file and re-import all...

Comment: Did that. It didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: and you gave IntelliJ the proxy connection settings? (just in case) - `File > Settings > HTTP Proxy`

Comment: Delete the .lastUpdated files, or just delete your whole local repository, and try again.

Comment: @costania see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. Maven proxy is configured in settings.xml: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder It worked like a charm! Can you please add this as an answer so that I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven proxy is [configured in settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) (usually `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`).

```
<settings>
  .
  .
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  .
  .
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

Right Click on POM --> Maven --> Open Settings.xml