# mvn clean install works without error message but cant find library in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

My maven environment or IntelliJ may get some issue. I can compile project with mvn clean install at command line, but in IntelliJ, it still says can't find some library. For example:

It gives a red flag saying can't find "deeplearning4j-examples-parent", but actually it exists. still, I can run program in this project in IntelliJ. But the red flag is annoying.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-examples-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </parent>
```

Is there a way in IntelliJ to debug this type of red flags? In Eclipse, there is a clean project options that usually helps.

**Edit:**
I added a screenshot. The problem now is no any red flag in pom.xml or code, but some red flags in the plugins, also some red flags in dependencies shown in this "Maven Project" view. No any red flags in pom. mvn clean install works all fine. Didn't report anything missing.

[image]

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply restarting the IDE?
 Otherwise, **Invalidate caches /restart** might help you:
**File --> Invalidate caches /restart**.

More information on clearing the cache can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Comment: @user697911 Have you tried reimporting the Maven dependencies? Click on "Maven" in the right side menu, right click on your projects name and select "Reimport". Afterwards, restart IntelliJ and see if it's resolved.
If that still doesn't work for you, a hard reset of the project might be the only way. Deleting the .idea folder (back it up first) and then reimporting the project in IntelliJ. 
Please let me know if this helps.