# Non-managed pom.xml file found (Unable to import maven project in IntelliJ)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I could not import my maven project in IntelliJ. The project has `pom.xml` file, but the IntelliJ does not load it. Check the log below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Comment: It's about memory. I think my problem is about network, but thanks for suggestion!

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept just the block below in `etc/hosts` and that works:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```