# IntelliJ is not recognizing some of the classes/methods... while the application is working just fine

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to Java/Linux/Maven/IntelliJ. When I look at the script serving to build the the code, I see something like this:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Long story short, the code is compiling just fine. I can open the browser and use the application normally.

However, when I open the code in IntelliJ, some of the class are highlighted in red `Cannot resolve symbol` or `cannot resolve method`, on and on.

I've rebuilt a couple of time, re-import the project, but still experiencing the same issue. Another developer has followed the same steps and is not experiencing the same issues.

Is there any reason, IntelliJ is not recognizing those classes/methods?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. Delete `.idea` directory and reimport from `pom.xml`.

Comment: @oleksander, invalidate caches/restart didn't solve the problem

Comment: @CrazyCoder, Sorry. I didn't see that another comment was added.

Comment: Still no luck. I've closed and re-imported the project, accepting every items, but IntelliJ is still not recognizing some of the classes.

Comment: Please share the logs and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run "File | Invalidate Caches"

Answer (score 0):

If you are still reading, possibly some coding confusion.  For me, there were similarly named objects in the repository and services, and so I was barking up the wrong tree in looking for a problem with IntelliJ.