# Intellij Maven - Jars are not downloaded

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I am currently using Intellij 2017.3.1.

I am trying to import a maven project from Github (File -> New -> Project from version control -> Github).

The project is imported successfully.

Later when I select "Add as a maven project" link, only the .pom files (of the dependencies) are being downloaded. The .jar files are NOT downloaded.Since the jar files are NOT downloaded I am getting "Cannot resolve method/symbol" errors.

I tried everything from reimporting the project, deleting the .idea files, reinstalling the IDE...but no luck.

It was working fine yesterday (was using the same IDE), don't know whats changed since then.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Answer (score 0):

When I uncheck the following option it does work:

Settings > Maven > Importing > Use Maven3 to import project