# Java connot find symbol "class JSONException" after adding maven dependeny

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij to develop a Java project. However, I've been stuck in a annoying dependency problem. I'm trying to import:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
```

But when I hit run, the compiler gives me the following errors:

```
Error:(23, 16) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JSONException
  location: package org.json
Error:(34, 44) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JSONException
  location: class com.test.util.metrics.ClientTest
```

At first it seems to be a typical maven dependency problem, but it turns out I still failed to solve it. I've tried:

1/ add json dependency to .xml file:

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<jsonSimple.version>1.1</jsonSimple.version>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>${jsonSimple.version}</version>
</dependency>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenCompilerPlugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
...
```

2/ In Intellij, hit Maven and `Reimport`

3/ In Intellij, hit Maven and `Generate Source and Update Folders`

4/ In Intellij, hit Maven and `Download Sources and Documentation`

But none of the above 4 works, still the same error message.

Could anyone give me some suggestions on this? I know it's a daily problem, but I still cannot solve this... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate the caches and restart IntelliJ? Sometimes there is nothing wrong with your dependencies (you can verify it by running mvn clean install from command line for example). In such cases there is probably a corrupt cache in IntelliJ causing the issues. To invalidate: File -> Invalidates caches / restart -> click: Invalidate and restart.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891

Comment: @PimHazebroek thanks for this suggestion, but still not working

Comment: @Bruce Young, too bad. Do you have the same result when running maven from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Try below dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this will work..

Comment: try force updating maven