# Maven issue update and dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

[image]

I go this problem with maven, something happened when I tried to udate it. Now its just eating up hadrdrive space, I had 10 GB free but it was not enough for update.

All my dependecies were red before i tried to update. Has anyone a clue on whats going on?

The exception is in swedish and says that I got no disk space left, but I had like 10 gb when i started.

Comment: And did you check if you have any space left on your drive? Can you run Maven on the command line for the project?

Comment: I had like 500mb when i cancelled the update, now I got 3gb. How do I do that?

Comment: Try to clear local repository to free up some space (in case you have there some old dependencies which are not in use) and run update again. And to run Maven in command line go to the project folder and run `mvn clean install`

Comment: @Seno Delete IDE system folder (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519), then let it reindex the repository, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. You may need several gigabytes free for the repository index in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you this did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete IDE [system folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519), then let it re-index the repository, see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891).

You may need several gigabytes free for the repository index in IntelliJ IDEA.