# Dependencies added but can't import correctly?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jde.jimie.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>jde-jimie-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        </dependency>
```

But when I tried to import a library from it, it says can't resolve the symbol.

```
import com.jd.jimie.data.sdk.eDataClient;
```

Specifically, in IntelliJ, it shows that "can't resolve symbol 'data'".

I restarted IntelliJ, but the problem persists.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Comment: Where do you get the above dependency? Do you really want to use a SNAPSHOT?