# How to configure default project build in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

We have a very complex project with tons of legacy code. The maven tests are hopelessly broken so we don't maintain or run them. I cannot remove them from the project, so I have to work around them. All our dev processes use IntelliJ so that is not an option. It is essential to get a successful build or IntelliJ cannot cross reference the project properly.

I can run 'mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true' from the command line in the root directory and it works.

In IntelliJ I have a maven run/debug configuration that corresponds to the root pom.xml, and it builds everything correctly. I can right click and build individual modules and they build correctly. But if I click the "build project" button or enable autobuild (for JRebel) then I get build errors. At first it was trying to build all the test code we don't use (and which is excluded from the root run/debug config) so I excluded those directories in the module dependencies, and now it is complaining about Groovy Ivy @grab... which works with the maven build or module build, but fails for project build.

I figure the project build (Ctrl-F9) must be using a completely different configuration than what's in the project root, but I can't find it in the maze of configuration dialogs.

It would also be fine if I could just bind the "project build" to the correct run/debug maven configuration.

Where can I find the build settings for the project root, or if I can't do that, can I bind it to a specific maven goal?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186885/why-does-build-project-fail-whereas-run-maven-configuration-succeed

Comment: Ah yes, the same issue. I'll mark this duplicate. Thanks.