# IntelliJ IDEA cannot resolve symbol 'openqa'

Tags: java, maven, selenium, intellij-idea

**Below are the import statements.**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```

**Below are the dependencies added.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven has successfully downloaded all the Selenium jars. Still the import statements show 'Cannot resolve symbol apache' and 'Cannot resolve symbol openqa' errors.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and updating the project?

Comment: @steven35 : Yes.

Comment: Are these ``dependency`` elements in the ``dependencies`` element or in the ``dependencyManagement`` element in your pom? just to make sure...

Comment: Have you checked on plain command line?

Comment: @f1sh : It's in 'dependencies'.

Comment: @khmarbaise : Yes.

Comment: And the result is? Works etc. without any error ?

Comment: @AkashChaudhuri if it builds from the command line Maven without errors and the error is present only in IntelliJ IDEA, please try to delete `.idea` directory and reimport the project. In case it doesn't help, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891 for the diagnostics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the jar files here: https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

Then add them in intellij via `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Modules`.

Click the `Dependencies` Tab.

Click the plus `+`.

Add all the extracted jars from the zip you downloaded including those inside and outside the `lib` folder.

Select them all and `Apply`.

[image]