# Can't use external dependency (installed by Maven) in IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I created a pom.xml that includes the XML to import JUnit 4.  I opened up project in IntelliJ.  It seems to have downloaded the external dependency, but when I try to use the dependency in an import statement, IntelliJ can't recognize it.

Here are the steps I took from the beginning:

1. I created a pom.xml.
2. mkdir MAVEN
3. mv pom.xml MAVEN
4. Open IntelliJ
5. File > open > pom.xml
6. cd ~/MAVEN
7. mkdir -p src/main/java
8. Go back to IntelliJ
9. Right click on src -> mark directory as root

I believe that Maven imported everything correctly because I can see JUnit as a dependency in the project directory: https://imgur.com/TdJq7PK

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvn-prac</atifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I attempt to use a common class from JUnit, such as `import org.junit.Test;`, IntelliJ can't recognize the symbol.

I have attempted both `mvn clean` and `mvn install` in the root of the project, and neither seemed to help.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you set a proper JDK for your project in IntelliJ?

Comment: Delete .idea directory and use Import Project instead. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891 if importing doesn't set roots correctly or doesn't configure the dependencies. It should be performed automatically for Maven projects. Your dependency has `test` scope, make sure the tests are in `src/test/java` so that they can see this dependency.

Comment: @CrazyCoder the entire problem was because of the test scope.  I just deleted that line and it picks everything up.  I was using the maven docs on apache's website and didn't even bother to care about what <scope></scope> actually did.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `test` scope, JUnit dependency will be available only for the tests located in `src/test/java`, but not to the classes in `src/main/java`.

Either remove the `<scope>test</scope>` line in `pom.xml` or move your tests to the proper Test Sources root.