# Why java pacakges are not loading in intelliJ ideda

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I [followed a tutorial](https://www.learningjournal.guru/article/kafka/configuring-intellij-idea-for-kafka/) and get this dependency file in maven project in intelliJ IDEA 2018.3

My ***pom.xml***

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>kafka.sample.firstProject</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-first-sample</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <kafka.version>2.1.0</kafka.version>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plug

ins>
            <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Kafka Clients-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Kafka Streams-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Log4J2 binding for SLF4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JUnit5 Jupiter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JUnit 5 Jupiter Engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JUnit 5 Jupiter Parameterized Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

but whenever i try to run my build it throws this:

[image]

> Error:(3, 41) java: package org.apache.kafka.clients.producer does not
>   exist and **so on ...**

Even after trying to run maven build still the problem persist.

Believe it or not i have get stuck in this problem from last many days.

Edit:
As @Parsecer asked to show maven build log, i found that there is an error as well

> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Building kafka-first-sample 1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 0.329 s
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-20T09:10:30+05:00
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/34M
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org) -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What happens when you try rebuilding your project with *Build > Rebuild Project*

Comment: I've just added your kafka dependency in my own pom and build was successful. Have tried first Run maven build (green arrow) and then reimport (a left circle) that worked for me when I had some errors. Or try to clean install?

Comment: Could you show the output result of the Build - when you click Maven's green error? Is it BUILD SUCCESS or BUILD FAILURE?

Comment: Are those errors only for Kafka ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Comment: @parsecer thanks i found error in build as well. The log has shown

Comment: @Muhammad Faizan Khan Ok. Maven can be quite a pain. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My System was behind a Proxy which not allowing me to get these packages. I remove the proxy and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check settings of IntelliJ by Ctrl-Alt-S. Type 'Maven' and see if you have proper Maven distribution (not the bundled one).

2) Refresh your Maven project from the right hand side of IntelliJ window.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to several issues which normally fixed after an IDE restart. Well you can try several things,

1. Do a maven reimport
2. Do a maven Download sources and documentation
3. And restart the JIdea IDE

You can try to use a latest maven version and see also.