# Outside dependencies not being installed in my IntelliJ DropWizard project?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, intellij-idea, dropwizard

I am attempting to import these 2 Maven dependencies into my project:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.11.578
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.11.578

I added them to my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <groupId>lspireback</groupId>
    <artifactId>lspireback</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>lspireback</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <dropwizard.version>0.9.1</dropwizard.version>
        <mainClass>lspireback.lspirebackApplication</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.578</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.578</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.4</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                                <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.10.3</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I opened the project in IntelliJ, right clicked Download Sources on the pom.xml file, clicked Re-Import, still get an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'aws'" over my import statement (Check "OfferingMemo.java" for where the error occurs). Here is the project: https://github.com/SixteenDollars/help

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/i7LgMPF.png). Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Comment: I don't really understand the answer in that link

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear, you have to check the logs to understand why it doesn't work for you or [contact IntelliJ IDEA support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) for help if you can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: I don't really understand anything it's saying in the log

Comment: Share the log with the support team to get help with this problem.