# How to Solve Maven Plugin Errors in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Whenever I create a new Maven project in IntelliJ, I always get these errors.

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.8.2

How can I solve these plugin errors?[image: Error messages I get when trying to sync my new and untouched project.]

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.kebaranas.croppynet</groupId>
    <artifactId>croppy-net-backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

My log file

```
2019-09-07 10:44:42,525 [  60453]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.1.0 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.1.0
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.resolvePlugin(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:1119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.1.0
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:3.1.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:3.1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:3.1.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:3.1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:400)
    ... 24 more
2019-09-07 10:44:44,045 [  61973]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-09-07 10:44:44,156 [  62084]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 0ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-09-07 10:44:44,413 [  62341]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 256ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-09-07 10:44:44,783 [  62711]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M3 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M3
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.resolvePlugin(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:1119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M3
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M3 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M3 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:400)
    ... 24 more
2019-09-07 10:44:44,829 [  62757]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M1 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.resolvePlugin(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:1119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M1
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:400)
    ... 24 more
2019-09-07 10:44:44,860 [  62788]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M1 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.resolvePlugin(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:1119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M1
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:400)
    ... 24 more
2019-09-07 10:44:44,896 [  62824]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.8.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.8.2 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.8.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.8.2
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.resolvePlugin(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:1119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.8.2
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:3.8.2 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:3.8.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:3.8.2 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:3.8.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:400)
    ... 24 more
2019-09-07 10:44:50,797 [  68725]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/kebaranas/IdeaProjects/croppynetbackend' croppynetbackendRunManager took 16 ms 
2019-09-07 10:45:33,435 [ 111363]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appEditorColorsManagerImpl took 11 ms 
2019-09-07 10:45:33,466 [ 111394]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project '/home/kebaranas/IdeaProjects/croppynetbackend' croppynetbackendKotlinCommonCompilerArguments took 14 ms
```

Comment: There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57699705/104891), but the user didn't provide sample project/logs. Hope you can can share the details to get help. Also make sure Maven is not in offline mode in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I just changed my plugin version number but it still does not work. Same error, different version. My maven is also not in offline mode.

Comment: I also matched the pictures you sent to the other similar question, including the settings.xml.

Comment: @CrazyCoder updated my question

Comment: Do you have a proxy with the self signed certificates? Did you install the root CA into the JVM used to run Maven from IntelliJ IDEA? See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220026.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I am quite a newbie programmer, so I am not quite sure if I did those things you specified. As far as I can explain, I just used Intellij as it is when I installed it, while I installed my Maven through apt-get maven (Ubuntu).

Comment: Do you connect to the Internet via a proxy? Did you configure any proxy for Maven per https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html?

Comment: @CrazyCoder For some unknown reason, I was able to fix it by adding a settings.xml file to my .m2 folder and deleting the .m2 repository folder.

Comment: What I did to resolve this was to clear up the artifacts of those plugins in the local repository and then do the rebuild again.

Comment: if my answer solved your issue, could you please mark it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I see in your log detail you have network connectivity problem to access remote repository of `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`

check above URL accessibility from browser then run following command to force Maven reattempt to execute from cmd as following

```
mvn clean install -U
```

-U will force Maven without waiting for next interval

Comment: Not marked as correct, worked for me though.

Answer (score 22):

I was also facing this issue and after some research, I manually run this command and it worked

`mvn dependency:resolve`

this will resolve the missing dependencies and plugins

Hope this works for you as well!!

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!