# Unable to import the Maven module in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to open this module in Intellij:
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/javaxval

The steps followed by me:

1. Go to required directory javaxval/ in my local and

> mvn clean install.

2. Open the pom.xml inside javaxval/ and open it as a project.

But Intellij is not syncing with the libraries mentioned in pom.xml as I can see in libraries section in Project Structure settings. Also, because of that, I can see lot of compilation errors.

Any idea what is the issue I am facing and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to reimport modules in intellij.

Comment: I tried to build the project again from Build->Build Project but then it fails with "Error:(10, 18) java: type annotations are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable type annotations)"

Comment: Reimport I have tried multiple times but no success.

Comment: Change compiler setting to 1.8 and try building your app.

Comment: I did all these steps but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project [imports and builds fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSdG7.png) in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2 version using the bundled Maven 3.6.1 for importing and JDK 1.8.

If it doesn't import/build for you, perform the diagnostics and check the logs [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891). Make sure the parent pom file is present in the directory tree on your disk.

Comment: I can see the dependencies in external Libraries section on left side but still my code is showing errors: https://imgur.com/a/7Nlzkj9

Comment: Your screenshot shows JDK dependency, not the other dependencies. There should be [a lot more](https://i.imgur.com/fRB998l.png).

Comment: Yeah. They are not coming. I check the logs u suggested above: https://pastebin.com/VYK5JSi9. But not sure if its a regular error or something I am missing.

Comment: What [JDK](https://i.imgur.com/Jt7zZDm.png) and [Maven](https://i.imgur.com/kJSGf3s.png) versions are used for importing? Does it help if you reset `~/.m2/settings.xml` to the defaults or delete it? What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use?

Comment: I think it might be the issue. Whenever I am re-importing the project, the java version here changes back to 1.5. https://imgur.com/a/qq4bRwT

Comment: JDK version is 1.8 and maven is 3.3.9. I don't see this file: ~/.m2/settings.xml. IntelliJ version is 2018.3

Comment: The error in the log: `Caused by: com.google.inject.OutOfScopeException: Cannot access Key[type=org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession, annotation=[none]] outside of a scoping block`. [Related bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200272). Solution: update to the latest IntelliJ IDEA version: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

Comment: Yeah. So, looks like it was the issue with this Intellij version. I updated to 2019 one and it works fine now. Thanks a lot for your help.