# Maven: All Plugins & Dependencies are underlined Red

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

ANY IDEAS?? I downloaded a Maven project for IntelliJ and cannot build it. I get errors for dependencies and plugins:

(SOLVED: THIS was because I was trying to run it on my work laptop in work, and the company firewall was blocking me from downloading from the public Maven repository. Thank you)

[VIEW BUILD LOG HERE](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AppGz5Z79iM-imaa_o_NLjlwivHn)

[VIEW IDEA LOG HERE](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AppGz5Z79iM-imf1-Zuf2xDH-RcH?e=FWcm1q)

[image: MAven]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. At least the logs are needed to investigate further.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you. Logs added.

Comment: The build log doesn't help, attach idea.log or all the logs instead. Help | Compress Logs and Show in ...

Comment: @CrazyCoder-  Done. Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like some connection issue, Maven is not able to download the dependencies from the repository. Make sure Internet connection is available and your antivirus/firewall is not blocking the downloads. Try running `mvn clean package` in the command line to ensure that it completes without any errors.

Comment: He might also need configure connectino via a proxy, and to check his `settings.xml` is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From reviewing the log files, its as people have mentioned IntelliJ is not able to actually download the dependencies.

The reason why is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-aop:pom:4.1.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

This typically can occur when all your external traffic is being routed by a corporate proxy that is performing a man-in-the-middle type of scan where the traffic is decrypted, scanned and then re-encrypted.

We experience the same thing in our office so our solution was:

- Install your own version of the java SDK (Ex. using [SDKMan](https://sdkman.io/))
- In your new install import into the default trust store the certificates required to validate the new certificate chain

  - Helps to access the URL in Chrome to view the [certificate chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKomy.png))
  - If it doesn't look like the Screenshot then there is a proxy
- Update IntelliJ so the `Project SDK` is the new one
- Update IntelliJ so `JDK for importer` is the new one
- Click the `Reimport All Maven Projects` in IntelliJ

This should allow it to continue to work without problems, alternatively in IntelliJ you can run the adhoc maven goal of:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

And it should install all the required dependencies into the local maven cache by ignoring all the SSL certificate problems however this is ***generally a bad idea***.

At this point you can then click the `Reimport All Maven Projects` in IntelliJ to have it refresh but I found this always doesn't work as IntelliJ sometimes downloads additional plugin dependencies that it can get hung up on that are outside of the `clean install` goals.

Comment: You were right... It was because I was trying to run it on my work laptop in work, and the company firewall was blocking me from downloading from the public Maven repository. Thank you.