# unable to add library for itext in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, itext

I am following the mentioned tutorial for generating the report in Intellij through text.
As per the Instruction i tried to download the library **"Project structure->Library->Add(maven)"**
and gave the library link **"com.itextpdf.maven:itextdoc:2.0.0"** as per the instruction but it is throwing below error.
**No files were downloaded for com.itextpdf.maven:itextdoc:2.0.0**.
Can someone pls help in this.
Tutorial followed: **"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWqduyt1ck0"** --> 0.20 secs

Comment: Please check the IDE logs, it looks like Maven is not working properly on your system, could be some issue related to the proxy/network. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. Proof of working: https://i.imgur.com/07vbpuD.png
https://i.imgur.com/nxTMpEz.png
https://i.imgur.com/VZdmXOr.png .

Comment: Thank you, as i checked in IDE logs, above error is been generated. As already suggested by you, will it be because of proxy/network related issue?

Comment: Yes, you may need to configure the proxy for Maven: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html and in IntelliJ IDEA as well: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-http-proxy.html . Only you know how your network works and what is required to connect to this host

Comment: **INFO** - MavenRepositoryServicesManager - java.net.UnknownHostException: repository.jboss.org 
java.io.IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: repository.jboss.org
**INFO** - ibrary.RepositoryAttachHandler - Failed to collect dependencies at com.itextpdf.maven:itextdoc:jar:2.0.0 
org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at com.itextpdf.maven:itextdoc:jar:2.0.0

Comment: I work for iText Software for almost 6 years, and I have never heard of an artifact `com.itextpdf.maven:itextdoc:2.0.0`. What is that???

Comment: Looks like the *iTextDoc Maven Plugin* was a side project of a developer who worked at iText Software 9 years ago (I found his personal blog). The source code of that plugin is nowhere to be found in any of the git repos at iText Software, nor on any of the backups of the old SVN repos on SourceForge. It depends on an ancient version of iText, `5.1.2` (August 2011), while the maintenance release of iText 5 `5.5.13.1` (June 2019) and the current version of iText 7 is `7.1.11` (literally yesterday, 6 April 2020). That old version of iText has known security bugs, use at your own risk!!!