# Idea Intellij: Ubuntu and Maven: Idea dependency not found error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to import dependencies in Maven via Idea Intellij, however I get a `Dependency [version] not found` error:

[image]

It happens for all dependencies in `pom.xml`.

I checked the local repository `/home/<User_Name>/.m2` folder and the jars are there:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So the jars exist, but Idea doesn't see them.
I do reload Idea's Maven by clicking the left round button:

[image]

It worked fine on Windows, but doesn't on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. You need to check the logs.

Comment: Does a `mvn clean install` work outside of IntelliJ (directly using the command line) ? Just trying to understand if the jars can be read by the terminal.

Comment: Yes, it works fine - `BUILD SUCCESS`. Also, I can use the dependency libraries in my code - the imports work fine. The only issue is that the versions are red in `pom.xml` but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to `IntelliJ IDEA` -> `Preferences` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Maven` -> `Importing` and mark the options like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: have you checked IntelliJ is using the right .m2 repository that you have configured?
(you can check it in: IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Local Repository)

Comment: Yes, it's in `/home/username/.m2/repository`, but the Override checkboxes are not checked. Should they be?

Comment: If paths are okay, then you don't need to override them. Other thing you can try is to force recreation of the configuration of your project: 1) close all IntelliJ windows 2) Go to you project folder and delete .idea/ directory and *.iml files 3) Open again your project with IntelliJ and if a popup appears asking you to 'Enable Auto import' then you have to confirm the operation.

Comment: No, still no luck. Somehow one dependency - `okhttp` isn't highlighted in red, while the other two - `gson` and `hibernate-core` are. Very weird behaviour.